# Apple Account Country Change

Tags: itunes

I really need to change my apple account country. I would like to see a TV show but I can only find it in the US store, and because I am in the Emirati store, it won't show up in that store. I do not understand why apple has placed the 'country store' system because when someone in a different country wants to buy a certain item, they aren't allowed to. Can I change my account store or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has separated the store into different countries because the rights to movies and shows can be owned by different companies in each country. For example a film might be distributed by Paramount in the United States and 20th Century Fox in the rest of the world (as was the case with James Cameron's Titanic). So Apple has to make separate deals with these companies to distribute their content in the store.

You can change the country attached to your account, but then in Apple's own words: "[After you change the country of your account, you won't see the items you purchased from the previous country’s store in the Purchased section.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201389)"

To change the country you may need a payment option located in that country. Again in Apple's own words: "[only German credit cards can be used to buy content from the German iTunes and App stores](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201389)".

Life would be easier for us if this wasn't the case, but unfortunately Apple has to follow the rules of the people who own the content they are distributing through their stores.